# What are current open questions in quantum measurement research?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements

Here we go, another question about quantum measurement... but bear with me.

When asking about quantum measurement one inevitably runs into discussions of various interpretations of quantum theory, different views about what the so-called "measurement problem" actually is and a whole lot of meta-physical or philosophical questions. That's fine and related issues have been discussed at length, on physics.SE and elsewhere.

At the same time, it is clear that there are many currently open questions in the **physical sector** of quantum measurement or quantum detector research. They are often connected to upcoming quantum technologies (such as quantum computing, quantum sensing etc) and also involve practical issues.

**My questions are:**

- What are concrete open questions in quantum measurement research that are relevant to physical applications and practical implementations of quantum technologies?
- What is the current status in answering these questions?

---

To be perfectly clear: This is explicitly *not* a question about interpretations of quantum theory, which [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) do not disagree in their experimental outcomes. Their theoretical differences are therefore not relevant to this question and any answer considering interpretations is misplaced, unless a clear computational advantage is provided thereby.

Comment: For the record, I firmly disagree with the close reason and do not intend to edit the question.